# Spring Data neo4j bad performance in getting data from Neo4j database

Tags: spring, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to make a simple query to get the 1st depth relationships for a particular node. I ran a couple tests to check the time taken for spring to get the data. The time taken is around 1.2 seconds even though the number of returned objects is 1 or 1000.

Just to verify this behavior, I wrote a simple python script and executed the same query only to see that it takes just 40 ms to fetch the result.

Could you please help me overcome this problem in Spring ? Thanks for your time.

Entity -

```
@NodeEntity(label = "Person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @Relationship(type="X",direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Set<Person> x;

    public Person()
    {}

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;   
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Repository -

```
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.Query;
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {

    @Query("match (n:Person)-[]->(k:Person) where n.name = {name} return k.name limit 1;")
    List<String> findPeople(String name);
}
```

findPeople is taking 1 seconds overall to get one object back from the database .

Comment: Without your code, how one can help you? Please share your code.

Comment: I have updated the code. Please help me out . Thanks

Comment: The question is how do you verify the 1.2 seconds it takes? An integration test sounds reasonable with startup etc.